# How to download the Contact attached in an email using EWS API?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

When attachment is Email I could simply get the mime content and save it. But when the attachment is Contact I am not able to get the MimeContent.  Here is the code

`itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
 MimeContent mc = itemAttachment.Item.MimeContent;
   //Convert it to bytes
  byte[] contentBytes = mc.Content;`

When attachment is contact I am getting below exception

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException occurred 
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=MIME conversion is not supported for
>   this item type.   Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.ThrowIfNecessary()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalGetAttachments(IEnumerable`1
>   attachments, Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties,
>   ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAttachment(Attachment
>   attachment, Nullable`1 bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment.InternalLoad(Nullable`1
>   bodyType, IEnumerable`1 additionalProperties)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemAttachment.Load(IEnumerable`1
>   additionalProperties)
>          at Presensoft.JournalEmailVerification.EmailVerification.DownloadFailedAttachments(EmailMessage
>   msg, JournalEmail journalEmail) in C:\Users\sameer\Presensoft\Email
>   Archiving\Presensoft.JournalEmailVerification\EmailVerification.cs:line
>   605   InnerException:

What is the proper way to download and save Contact attachment?

Answer (score 1):

**Saving as a contact in Exchange**

Using MimeContent on a contact will not work because the server does not support the conversion. You can get MimeContent for a contact, you just can't save MimeContent as a contact.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to save an attached contact. What I would suggest is to manually clone the contact. Using EWS Managed API you can access the ItemAttachment as a contact. You would then need to create a new contact on the server, copy all the properties from the attached contact to the new contact using `TryGetProperty()`, then save the new contact.

I know it would make sense to just use the **Save** method on the contact object when you access the ItemAttachment. The problem is that there is a read only property on the object, **IsAttachment**, that is set to true and will not allow the object to be saved. If you try you will get an exception that this method is not available for attachments.

**Saving as a .vcf file**

If you are trying to save the contact to your local file system there are just a couple lines of code necessary.

```
itemAttachment.Load(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
File.WriteAllBytes("Contact.vcf", itemAttachment.Item.MimeContent.Content);
```

I hope this information helps. If this does resolve your problem, please mark the post as answered.

Thanks,

--- Bob ---

Comment: My requirement is to save the attachment in the file system as a separate file. Any ways to achieve this?

Comment: I was able to get the MimeContent and save the file with my test code. I updated the answer to add the two lines of code I used after determining that the attachment was an ItemAttachment and the ItemClass of the attachment was IPM.Contact.

Comment: Bob, itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent)) and itemAttachment.Load(ItemSchema.MimeContent) what is the difference?

Comment: From what I can tell there is no difference. I've tried both with my code and get the same results.

Comment: Bob, that is the same code I am using and with only difference of  itemAttachment.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent)) use . I am getting the same exception anyways. I am wondering how is it working for you. Is there any settings in exchange to make it work??

Comment: Ahhh!!! the code is working for me in my local system and local exchange setup..it is only that this is not working while trying to grab mime content from Clients exchange box.. Client is using Exchange 2010 without any service pack... Is there any dependency on exchange version??